# Sol regular expression query error for starting with u

Tags: lucene, solrj

I am using solr 3.I can search starting with `attributeValue:\hin*` But it fails for`attributeValue:\uo*`

```
error is
 "error": {
    "msg": "org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Non-hex character in Unicode escape sequence: o",
    "code": 400
  }
```

Issue is \u I can not exclude u as user can search anything from type+search.

Answer (score 0):

When you're searching for something starting with `\u` it's treated as a Unicode symbol. Of course `o` symbol isn't allowed to be in the Unicode symbol. If you want to search for `\` you need to escape it. More info on this:

> Lucene/Solr supports escaping special characters that are part of the query
>   syntax. The current list special characters are
>
> `+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /`
>
> To escape these character use the `\` before the character